# Encoding of an incoming sms

Tags: android, encoding, sms

I need to know how to get the encoding of an incoming sms on my device using the [SmSMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html) class in my [broadcastreceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) class.

Obviously I can not use the code:

```
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
    msg_str += msgs[i].getMessageBody();
}
StringBufferInputStream buf = new StringBufferInputStream(msgs[0].getMessageBody());
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(buf);
String encode = reader.getEncoding();
```

Since this will return me the default encoding of java which is (UTF-8).

I need to check if the sms is in **GSM7** ,**8-bit** , or **UTF-16** encoding.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the [calculateLength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#calculateLength%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean%29) function of the [SMSMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html) class.

This returns an int[ 4 ] with int[ 0 ] being the number of SMS's required, int[ 1 ] the number of code units used, and int[ 2 ] is the number of code units remaining until the next message. int[ 3 ] is the encoding type that should be used for the message.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that SMS:s are encoded in [GSM 03.38](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38), typically. This is probably the "radio-specific encoding" the Android docs mention.

Comment: It will, but I need to check if the sms is in GSM7 ,8-bit , or UTF-16 encoding.(Just edited my question).

Answer (score 1):

Android already has the constant definition `ENCODING_16BIT`, `ENCODING_7BIT`, `ENCODING_8BIT`, `ENCODING_UNKNOWN` in the [SMSMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html) class which correspond to Data Coding Scheme in [3GPP TS 03.38](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/0338.htm). However, it's funny that they are not used in return value of public methods.

Hence, the best solution is:

1. Get the whole SMS TPDU bytes using `getPdu()`
2. Parse the bytes according to [3GPP TS 03.40](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/0340.htm) (section 9) to get the DCS byte (for SMS deliver: 1 byte TP-MTI/MMS/RP/UDHI/SRI, 2-12 bytes TP-OA, 1 byte TP-PID, and then the DCS byte)
3. Parse the DCS byte according to section 5 of 3GPP TS 03.38.

Sample code for parsing the DCS byte is as follow:

```
public static byte getSmsDcsType(byte dcs)
{
    // Notes:
    // ------
    // the (SMS) DCS value according to 3GPP TS 03.38 / TS 23.038 is coded as follow:
    // 0xxx00xx = GSM 7-bit default alphabet (packed format)
    // 0xxx01xx = 8-bit data (unpacked-format)
    // 0xxx10xx = UCS2 uncompressed format
    // 0xxx11xx = reserved
    // 10xxxxxx = reserved
    // 110xxxxx = GSM 7-bit default alphabet (packed format)
    // 1110xxxx = UCS2 uncompressed format
    // 111100xx = GSM 7-bit default alphabet (packed format)
    // 111101xx = 8-bit data (unpacked-format)
    // 11111xxx = reserved

    if (((byte) (dcs & (byte) 0x8C) == 0x00)
            || ((byte) (dcs & (byte) 0xE0) == (byte) 0xC0)
            || ((byte) (dcs & (byte) 0xFC) == (byte) 0xF0))
    {
        return SmsMessage.ENCODING_7BIT;
    }
    else if (((byte) (dcs & (byte) 0x8C) == 0x04) || ((byte) (dcs & (byte) 0xFC) == (byte) 0xF4))
    {
        return SmsMessage.ENCODING_8BIT;
    }
    else if (((byte) (dcs & (byte) 0x8C) == 0x08) || ((byte) (dcs & (byte) 0xF0) == (byte) 0xE0))
    {
        return SmsMessage.ENCODING_16BIT;
    }

    return SmsMessage.ENCODING_UNKNOWN;
}
```